# Calling override activity and not following activity life cycle

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to call the `onCreate` method from the `onPause` method. Is this possible?

Comment: Check this out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Whats the reason for it?

Comment: I noticed you unaccepted my answer... did you have any other questions that I didn't cover?

Answer (score 1):

No. You should never make any explicit calls to `onCreate` (or any other `Activity` lifecycle method for that matter). The system manages the `Activity` lifecycle for you, and explicitly calling these methods will only interfere.

Comment: If i make then what will happen..??

Comment: Why do you want to call `onCreate` from `onPause` in the first place?

Comment: I am making an app where if switch any specific activity den all the things done in onCreate should be redone. like edittext should be empty, etc

Comment: @user1371595 - For that make a method in that activity which recreate your view objects (like edittext and other views) and call it from onPause and onCreate() but never try to call onCreate() from onPause()

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar demand in several applications.  Create a separate (probably want it to be a private) method for doing all the dirty work and call from both places.  For example

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    //call your init function here
    init();
    ...
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause(); 
    //call your init function here
    init();
}

//your init stuff
private void init(){
    //do all of the stuff you need to do in onCreate and onPause here
    ...
}
```